# trying to find cause of Flex "RPC Error" pop-up

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I'm working with a Flex 4 application (MXML and ActionScript front-end using BlazeDS and Java back-end) and I am trying to find the origin of an error.

The user sometimes (maybe once a week) gets a pop-up window with "RPC Error" in their web browser. If they retry the operation, they get the same error. Restarting the browser or maybe just reloading the page makes the error go away. Looking in the server log, I don't see any error on the server side. How can I figure out the cause of the RPC error? Can I configure some setting in the browser or Flash player to get additional info?

Thanks for any ideas. I've searched the web & some forums including SO but I've come up empty-handed.

Edit: in this case it appears the problem was loss of the network connection (user was connected via cell modem). I'm still interested in any ideas about how to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do my development in Firefox and using Firebug as a console.  When the Flex app starts, open up Firebug and look at the Net tab.  It will bring up all the RPC calls made while Flex is initializing, which can be very useful for these kinds of bugs.